# "FizzBuzz" function doesn't match expected output

Tags: python, function, fizzbuzz

In a Python course, I'm told to create a FizzBuzz function that takes in a list of integers provided by the course's online grader:

```
def fizzbuzz(intlist):
```

Other parameters are: I cannot modify the input list, must return a list with both integers and strings, and don't need to call the function. Here's what I've come up with so far:

```
def fizzbuzz(intlist):
    result = [ ]
    i = 0
    for i in range(1, 101):
        if i %3 == 0 and i %5 == 0:
            result.append(str('FizzBuzz'))
        elif i %3 == 0:
            result.append(str('Fizz'))
        elif i %5 == 0:
            result.append(str('Buzz'))
        else:
            result.append(i)
        i += 1
    return result
```

The online grader says that my output doesn't match the test case for numbers 1-30 and 1 - 100.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

---

Edit 7/29/15 3:00pm PST

Here is my new code, reflective of your recent suggestions:

```
def fizzbuzz(intlist):
    result = [ ]
    for i in intlist:
        if i %3 == 0 and i %5 == 0:
            result.append('FizzBuzz')
        elif i %3 == 0:
            result.append('Fizz')
        elif i %5 == 0:
            result.append('Buzz')
        else:
            result.append(i)
        return result
```

When I enter the above code in the auto-grader, it says that I haven't defined

```
intlist
```

How should I define

```
intlist
```

in line 3 when the list of numbers is supposed to be supplied by the auto-grader?

The grader will run

```
fizzbuzz(intlist)
```

to verify my function returns the correct output. I believe I am incorrectly assuming that the argument

```
intlist
```

passed to the fizzbuzz function should be the name of the list of integers I'm taking in and assessing at line 3.

Any further suggestions?

Comment: What output does your function produce? Do you know what the grader is expecting? Are there any errors?

Comment: You do not need to declare/increment the `i`variable by hand (ie remove `i=0`and `i += 1`lines).  Also,  'Fizz' with quote is already a string, so no need to transtype.

Comment: `intlist` is unused.

Comment: I think you're supposed to check the values in the input list (`intlist`) instead of the values in `range(1, 100)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have to loop over the contents of the intlist. You also do not have to initialize or increment i, as this is handled already by the for loop. By putting '' around the words FizzBuzz, Fizz and Buzz you've already made them into strings, so you don't have to explicitly call str(). If you want to use this function, you will first have to define a list and then call your function on it. I suspect the correct code will be:

```
def fizzbuzz(intlist):
    result = [ ]
    for i in intlist:
        if i %3 == 0 and i %5 == 0:
            result.append('FizzBuzz')
        elif i %3 == 0:
            result.append('Fizz')
        elif i %5 == 0:
            result.append('Buzz')
        else:
            result.append(i)
        return result

alist = [1,2,3]
fizzbuzz(alist)
```

Comment: You should replace `intlist[i]` with `i`. `i` is already one of the values in `intlist`.

Comment: @Maaike you could also mention that the `str()` around the literal strings are redundant.

Comment: Thanks so much, everyone! I did try replacing range(1, 101) with     (intlist) at some point and didn't have any luck. I took all your recommendations and changed my code to reflect them. The grader says "global name 'intlist' is not defined". Is this perhaps an issue with the grader?

Comment: @ErinAllard Can you post your full code here? Or is this your full code? You have to define intlist before you can use it. Does your assignment say anything about that?

Comment: @Maaike, thank you. I just posted the full code as an edit to my original question. I'm not sure how to code the definition for intlist since it's supposed to be supplied by the auto-grader. Do I just define it as "intlist = input()" ?

Comment: @ErinAllard You need to call your function on a list of integers. I'm not sure how your practise program works (maybe you have a a link to it?) but one way to define a list would be just say aname = [1,2,3] and then call fizzbuzz(1,2,3). I've edited my answer so you can see more clearly what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this line:

```
 for i in range(1, 101):
```

You are doing the fizzbuzz exercise for the numbers from 1 to 101, regardless of what is passed in to your function.  You should be looking at `i in intlist` instead.

Also, the `for` loop takes care of making sure the `i` has a different value each time you loop; you do not have to increment it yourself in the loop or initialize it before the loop.

Answer (score 0):

This Should Work.

```
def fizzbuzz(intList):
result = [ ]
for i in intList:
    if i %3 == 0 and i %5 == 0:
        result.append('FizzBuzz')
    elif i %3 == 0:
        result.append('Fizz')
    elif i %5 == 0:
        result.append('Buzz')
    else:
        result.append(i)
return result
```

Answer (score 0):

Even I am a rookie and was stuck at the same place as you are, finally i cracked it, this works:

```
def fizzbuzz(intList):
intlist1=list()
intlist1=intList
for i in range(len(intlist1)):
    if (intlist1[i]%3==0) and (intlist1[i]%5==0):
        intlist1[i]='FizzBuzz'
    elif (intlist1[i]%5==0):
        intlist1[i]='Buzz'
    elif (intlist1[i]%3==0):
        intlist1[i]='Fizz'
        i=i+1
return intlist1
```

Answer (score 0):

def fizzbuzz(x):
    s=""
    slist=[]
    for i in x:
        if i%3==0:
            s="fizz"
        if i%5==0:
            s=s+"Buzz"
        if s=="":
            s=i
        slist.append(s)
        s=""
    print slist